# Hyperbola and Ellipse in One Equation

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I just want to know the name of this equation below :

$$4y^4-45y^2+36y-9x^2=0$$

Actually i was obtanied from this following :

$$|z+2i|+|z-2i|=6$$

When i solve the locus representation of that it gives me a strange graph. Then i checked the solution manual and it said that the graph is ellipse.

Here is my progress :

$\begin{align}
&|x+i(y+2)|=6-|x+i(y-2)|\\
&\Leftrightarrow x^2 +(y+2)^2=36-12\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2} +(x^2+(y-2)^2)\\
&\Leftrightarrow 8y^2-36=-12\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}\\
&\Leftrightarrow 4y^4-36y^2+36=9(x^2+(y-2)^2)\\
&\Leftrightarrow 4y^4-45y^2+36y-9x^2=0
\end{align}$

Where is my mistake?

My graph is ellipse, but has hyperbola on the outside

But...
If i don't simplify this, i mean i just input this equation below (from my work at second line) in GeoGebra and it gives me the actual ellipse :

$$(y+2)^2-(y-2)^2-36=-12\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}$$

Comment: It's hard (impossible?) to say where you made a mistake if you don't show your work. :) ... That said, it *should be* clear that the desired locus is an ellipse, because $|z+2i|+|z-2i|=6$ is exactly the definition of a set of points whose distances from two fixed points (namely, $\pm 2i$) have a constant sum (namely, $6$).

Comment: I'll add my progress

Comment: I've added my work

Comment: How did you end up with $8y^2$ in the third line? That should be $8y$ since the second-degree terms on both sides of the previous equation cancel.

Comment: @amd yes... i think i made a mistake at the third line.